# How do I grab contents of a div only if the class in the div above has certain text in it

Tags: html, xml, xpath

```
<li class="amenities__item amenities__item--yes">
    <div class="amenities__icon amenities__icon--yes"></div>
    <div class="amenities__label">
      Parking
    </div>
  </li>
```

I want to grab the text "Parking" but ONLY if the div before it has the word "yes" in it.

I have been trying variations of:

```
//div[contains(class/following-sibling::text(), 'Yes')]
```

But seems I need this to be more specific somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
normalize-space(//div[contains(preceding-sibling::div[1]/@class, 'yes')])
```

will return the space-normalized string value of the `div` with an immediately preceding sibling `div` with `yes` in its `@class` attribute value.  For your posted example HTML, that will be:

```
Parking
```

If you instead wish to test that the string value of the preceding `div` equal `Yes`, then use this XPath:

```
normalize-space(//div[preceding-sibling::div[1] = 'Yes'])
```

---

**Update to address comment question about how to deal with multiple such `div` elements**

For the first XPath, you can select a nodeset (XPath 1.0) or a sequence (XPath 2.0+) of such `div` elements:

```
//div[contains(preceding-sibling::div[1]/@class, 'yes')]
```

The way you'd iterate over the resulting nodeset/sequence would depend upon the language hosting the XPath library.  Within XPath, should you know that you want, say, the 2nd such `div`, you can append `[2]`:

```
//div[contains(preceding-sibling::div[1]/@class, 'yes')][2]
```

Comment: This is great thanks. Can I ask you one more thing, there is a list of these divs, the ones that have a specific amenity then the class is "yes", some are  "no". How do I grab each yes one (as above), one by one? I tried fiddling with the [1] number on the div, but it won't pick them up.